# How to implement this ejecting and withdrawing portion of a window like a drawer?

Tags: cocoa

How to implement following effect with Cocoa:

[image]

<->
[image]

User can eject and withdraw right portion of window with a button.

**Update:** How to draw the vertical line in the tool bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually part of the window. When you click the button, the window and view just resize into their appropriate positions.

Check out [NSViewAnimation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSViewAnimation_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Thanks. But how to draw the vertical line in tool bar?